# Can an entire list/library be versioned?

Tags: list, versioning, version-history

It's possible to enable item versioning on lists and roll back to a previous version on that item. Can this be done for the entire list? So we can roll the whole thing back?

We accidentally modified a site column used in the list and lost some dropdown values for some choice columns across the site collection (`Update all list columns based on this site column` option was set to yes). It would be great to prevent this in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to hear that but lists themselves are not versioned, they cannot be rolled back.

You may want to consider database or site collection backup/restore. You may still lose some data depending upon the backup schedule.